# Building RIA services project without Visual Studio

Tags: wcf, msbuild, continuous-integration, code-generation, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to build RIA-enabled Silverlight project on the continuous integration server. There is no Visual Studio installed on it. Therefore I'm missing some libraries/targets.

What needs to be installed in order to build RIA project with only MSBuild?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really obvious but:

1. Install Ria Services: `msiexec /i RiaServices.msi SERVER=TRUE`
2. Copy `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server\Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.dll` from dev machine where Visual Studio is installed (since SERVER=TRUE does not install this assembly).
3. Remove (rename) `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets`

After that I managed to build it without Visual Studio.